# Generate Random Number between 2 constraints

Tags: delphi, random, delphi-xe8

I know the code from the Standard Delphi programming goes like this:

```
randomize();
i := random(5,10); // where i is an integer.
```

Then the value of `i` will be between 5 and 10. However how would I do that in Fire Monkey. The function requires a range but I have no idea how to create the range.

Searching Google or event the documents on [Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Random)'s website has been of no help either.

The function looks like this: `function Random(const ARange: Integer): Integer;`

Is this even possible, or am I looking the wrong places?
Should I rather write a function like this:

```
while ((i<= 64) and (i>= 91)) do
    i := Random(90);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RNG functions in Delphi are part of the RTL, defined in the `System` unit. As such the are available in FMX just as they are available in VCL. In short, FireMonkey is not really relevant.

The function that you are looking for is [`RandomRange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.RandomRange) from `System.Math`.

So, you might write:

```
Value := RandomRange(5, 10);
```

But note carefully this part of the documentation:

> **RandomRange** returns a random integer from the range that extends between AFrom and ATo (non-inclusive).

So, the function call above can only return the following values: 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. How would you word that in google ? "For future when others search for this issue"

Comment: @Jacques: What's wrong with *random range Delphi* or *random range integer Delphi*? Or just the help index, using *Random* (which returns *Random Support Routines* as the third listed result, and *RandomRange* as the 15th)?

Comment: Sorry - missed XE8 in the title. The help file search is *Help->Rad Studio Help->System Library Help*, search for *Random*, where *RandomRange* is the fourth item in the results list.

Comment: @KenWhite I actually didn't know what to search for any more. I search `random number generation firemonkey` and `generate random number between 2 values firemonkey` etc. I thought that the function had been altered between versions, the last time I used an embarcadero product was 5 years ago, back then it was as simple as `random(a,b)`

Comment: In Delphi, it was never `Random(a, b)`, as far as I know. It was either `myFloat := Random;` to get a floating point value in the range `[0.0, 1.0)`, IOW, excluding 1.0, or `myInteger := Random(a);` to get a value in the range  `0..a-1`. And, as David said, it has nothing to do with FMX. It belongs to the core runtime library.